# Prove that $a_{n}$ converges for $a_{1} \ge 2$ and $a_{n+1} = 1+ \sqrt{a_{n}-1}$ and find its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Prove that $a_{n}$ converges for $a_{1} \ge 2$ and $a_{n+1} = 1+ \sqrt{a_{n}-1}$ and find it's limit. First of all, what i did is to find the first four terms of the sequence.

$a_{2} = 1+ \sqrt{a_{1}-1} \ge 2$

$a_{3} = 1+ \sqrt{a_{2}-1} = 1+ \sqrt{\sqrt{a_{1}-1}} \ge 2$

$a_{4} = 1+ \sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{a_{1}-1}}} \ge 2$

Then I assume $a_{n} \ge 2 $ Witch means that $a_{n}$ it's lower bounded. I need to prove that it is a decreasing sequence and then $a_{n}$ would converge.

$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_{n}} = \frac{1+\sqrt{a_{n}-1}}{a_{n}} \le1$$ but i don't know how to prove that.  The limit, I don't know how to find it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Consider instead the sequence $b_n=a_n-1$.

Comment: @Mindlack How so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Then I assume $a_n\ge 2$

Note that you would have to prove that as well. Just because the first four terms are $\ge 2$, doesn't mean that you can conclude that for all $n$. However, induction should easily help you out there.

If you assume $a_n \ge 2$, then you get
$$a_{n+1} = 1 + \sqrt{\color{blue}{a_n} - 1} \ge 1 + \sqrt{\color{blue}{2} - 1} = 2.$$
Now, since $a_1 \ge 2$, induction tells you that $a_n \ge 2$ for all $n$.

---

Now, showing that $a_n$ is decreasing is easy because we have
$$a_n - 1 \ge 1$$
and thus,

$$a_n - 1 \ge \sqrt{a_n - 1}.$$

Rearranging the above gives us that
$$a_n \ge 1 + \sqrt{a_n - 1} \ge a_{n+1}.$$

This finishes the proof the way you intended it.

---

Note that the other answer gives a simpler alternative by considering $b_n = a_n - 1$.

---

Once you know that the sequence converges, you can find the limit as following:
$$a_{n+1} = 1 + \sqrt{a_n - 1} \implies \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}1 + \sqrt{a_n - 1}.$$
If $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = A$, then $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1} = A$ as well.
Moreover, $\sqrt{.}$ is continuous and thus, you may "take the limit inside". Thus, the above equation tells you
$$A = 1 + \sqrt{A - 1}$$
or $$A - 1 = \sqrt{A - 1}.$$
Squaring the above and solving it gives two solutions: $A = 1, 2$.
However, note that $a_n \ge 2$ for all $n$ and thus, $A \ge 2$ as well. With this, you can conclude that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \boxed{2}.$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Set $b_n=a_n-1$ ($b_1\ge 1$), then we have:

$$b_{n+1}=\sqrt{b_n}.$$

Also see that, $$b_2=b_1^{1/2}$$ $$b_3=b_2^{1/2}=b_1^{1/4}$$ $$b_4=b_3^{1/2}=b_1^{1/8}$$ $$...$$

can you finish?

Comment: Perfect, by using $b_{n} = a_{n} -1 $ i can easily prove that $b_{n+1} \le b_{n}$ (extreactly deacresing) and so is $a_{n}$. To show that it's lower bounded by 2 it alright the way i did it ?

Comment: I think you can solve it using a simpler idea. Try to find $b_n$ as a function of $b_1$.

Comment: I'm trying to find the limit as asked in the Exercise, I'm trying to find $b_{n}$ as a function of $b_{1}$. Is it $b_{n} = b_{1}^{\frac{1}{2^{(n-1)}}}$

Comment: @Karl: It is. Now you can find the limit

Comment: In this case, the limit is 1, but if not the limit would be in terms of $b_{1}$? Thanks

Comment: @Karl: Nope! The limit is $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Let prove it is decreasing

$$a_{n+1}-a_n=$$

$$1+\sqrt{a_n-1}-a_n=$$

$$\sqrt{a_n-1}(1-\sqrt{a_n-1})$$

but

$$a_n\ge 2\implies \sqrt{a_n-1}\ge 1$$
$$\implies 1-\sqrt{a_n-1}\le 0$$
$$\implies a_{n+1}-a_n\le 0$$
thus $ (a_n) $ is decreasing and bounded below, so it converges to $ L $ satisfying
$$L=1+\sqrt{L-1}\implies L\in\{1,2\}$$
$$\implies L=2$$